# Significance of "and not"?

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, operators

```
secret_word = "giraffe"
guess = ""
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_guesses = False

while guess != secret_word and not (out_of_guesses):
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Enter guess: ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True
        
if out_of_guesses:
    print("Out of Guesses, YOU LOSE!")
else:
    print("You win!")
```

I don't really understand what `and not(out_of_guesses):` does here...
Can someone break it down for me?
I understand that the `not` operator reverses the value of a boolean, but couldn't you just write `and(out_of_guesses):`?

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to remove a `not` without changing the meaning?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but wouldn't `and not(out_of_guesses)` set the value of `out_of_guesses` to `True`?

Comment: "wouldn't 'and not(out_of_guesses)' set the value of 'out_of_guesses' to 'True'" - no. The expression uses the opposite of the value of `out_of_guesses`, but `out_of_guesses` is unchanged.

Comment: Just FYI, the parenthesis are not necessary.  You can do `and not out_of_guesses` :-)

Answer (score 0):

`not(out_of_guesses)` simply reverses the variable's value to `True`, but only within the while condition.

The value of the variable will remain the same as previously defined.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that `not(out_of_guesses)` could be read as: "...and while `out_of_guesses` has not been activated" ?

Comment: @delta_stream, yes .